# How to assign the for loop values in variable in one line

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, simplify

So I have the following example of code; simultaneously iterates over multiple sequences combined with enumerate, assigning the values to tuple variable after which outputs it.

```
def PairValuesWithIndexToTuples(self,val1,val2):
  t =()
  for i, (a,b) in enumerate(zip(val1,val2)):
    t += (i,a,b)
  return t
```

What I want to achieve is something like this if it is possible: 
I have been searching around but I could not find yet a solution which achieves my results from the method written above:

```
def PairValuesWithIndexToTuples(self,val1,val2):
  t =()
  t += for i, (a,b) in enumerate(zip(val1,val2))
  return t
```

or

```
return t+= for i, (a,b) in enumerate(zip(val1,val2))
```

Comment: **Never** ask for one-liner. Instead, ask for short and clean code. Otherwise you should use `exec('for i,(a,b) in enumerate(zip(val1,val2)):\nt+=(i,a,b);')`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a generator expression to create the tuples, then [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) from that expression to get the flattened result

```
from itertools import chain

tuple(chain.from_iterable((i, a, b) for i, (a,b) in enumerate(zip(val1,val2))))
```

This looks much nicer as a multiline function

```
def pair_with_index(*its):
    e = enumerate(zip(*its))
    flattened = ((i, *t) for i, t in e)
    c = chain.from_iterable(flattened)
    return tuple(c)

pair_with_index([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
# (0, 1, 4, 1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 6)
```

Edit:

My original code (for a tuple of tuples) was

```
def pair_with_index(val1, val2):
    return tuple((i, a, b) for i, (a,b) in enumerate(zip(val1,val2)))

pair_with_index([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
# ((0, 1, 4), (1, 2, 5), (2, 3, 6))
```

Comment: That's a different result - You have a tuple of tuples rather than a tuple of values.

Comment: @FHTMitchell Fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @PatrickHaugh. I was actually looking for obtaining a tuple of tuples but I wanted to know if i could rewrite my code in a more optimised way. So instead of having 5 lines of code I could only have 2 or 3.

Comment: Looking at my first code snipped I wanted to know if I can achieve something like: def PairValuesWithIndexToTuples(self,val1,val2): return t+= for i, (a,b) in enumerate(zip(val1,val2))  or def PairValuesWithIndexToTuples(self,val1,val2):  t =()
  t += for i, (a,b) in enumerate(zip(val1,val2))
  return t

Comment: @nclaudiuf Is the output of my edit more what you're looking for?  The problem with posting examples with made-up syntax is that I'm not sure which result you're looking for.  Could you provide sample inputs/outputs?

Comment: Yes, the second comment, is exactly what I was looking for ! I am just new to python so i did not get it from your first post that I could do a return there. Thanks for the rewrite

Comment: I had voted your code up but, I do not have yet enough points to make a difference ...

Comment: You can also [accept answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), but please don't feel pressured to unless it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for a flattened list or a flattened tuple? Not clear from your question, so I'll just include everything.

```
In [79]: val1 = [1,2,3]

In [80]: val2=[4,5,6]

In [81]: [(i, a, b) for i, (a,b) in enumerate(zip(val1,val2))]
Out[81]: [(0, 1, 4), (1, 2, 5), (2, 3, 6)]

In [82]: [k for j in [(i, a, b) for i, (a,b) in enumerate(zip(val1,val2))] for k in j]
Out[82]: [0, 1, 4, 1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 6]

In [84]: tuple(k for j in [(i, a, b) for i, (a,b) in enumerate(zip(val1,val2))] for k in j)
Out[84]: (0, 1, 4, 1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 6)
```

Comment: Thnaks for the comment @Acharya. Its good to know I can also achieve that. I was though looking to get a tuples of tuples return. But I just wanted to optimise my code in shorter amount of code possible. You can have a look at the comment I posted to Patrick

Answer (score -2):

Because this is so much clearer...

```
sum(((i, a, b) for i, (a,b) in enumerate(zip(val1, val2))), ())
```

example:

```
val1 = 'hello'

val2 = range(5)

sum(((i, a, b) for i, (a,b) in enumerate(zip(val1, val2))), ())
# -> (0, 'h', 0, 1, 'e', 1, 2, 'l', 2, 3, 'l', 3, 4, 'o', 4)
```

Comment: [Append on tuples forms a monoid too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/952946/5267751)

Comment: `functools.reduce(lambda a,b: a+b, ((i, a, b) for i, (a,b) in enumerate(zip(val1, val2))))` is faster here -- I think `sum(x, [])` is O(n^2)

Comment: @MoxieBall [Yes it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python#comment77806270_952946)

Comment: I am wrong, functools.reduce is not faster. itertools.chain is the way to go.

Answer (score -2):

While I don't advocate abusing `sum`, it is possible to do this in order to concatenate tuples together

```
sum(tuples, ())
```

Or in your case

```
sum(((i, a, b) for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(val1, val2))), ())
```

It is important to note that this can be inefficient, given the behaviors of sum. And it is not quite as clear in this instance.

**Note**: I do not advocate using this in production code. It is merely to show that it is possible.

Comment: [Quadratic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python#comment77806270_952946)...

Comment: you just copied my answer

Comment: @FHTMitchell https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/how-should-we-deal-with-duplicate-answers

Comment: @FHTMitchell no, we just answered within 30 seconds of each other. Yours popped up as "new answer" right as I hit submit :)

Comment: @FHTMitchell I'd be willing to retract my answer, but I did not copy yours. And I resent the accusation given they were submitted within a few seconds of each other

Comment: @user202729 I was only gave this answer to show it was possible, not to advocate for it's usage. I have updated my answer accordingly